# Where are new folders in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: macos, visual-studio

In VS2015 on Mac with an ASP.NET CORE project, when I try to create a new folder by right clicking the project in the solution explorer > Add > Folder. But it says it already exist:

> File or directory name is already in use. Please choose a different
>   one.

I go into finder and see the folder is there. Why doesn't it display in VS2015?

Comment: Show the errors that VS for Mac displays, please. What kind of project template is that? How do you create a new folder, BTW?

Comment: Just updated the OP with that info.

Comment: @HansPassant: Where is this button you're referring to?